# Tensorflow Estimator: loss not decreasing when using tf.feature_column.embedding_column for a list of categorical variables

Tags: python, tensorflow, machine-learning, tensorflow-estimator

I'm very new to Tensorflow Estimator. I wonder if it's possible to pass an array of categorical variables as feature to the estimator and it automatically converts it to an array of embeddings. For example, the following is a record in a CSV file. It contains 2 lists of categorical variables(enclosed in brackets), "country" and "watch", 2 categorical variables, "day_of_week" and "day_period" and one target, "movie_id" in this case.

```
day_of_week,day_period,country,movie_id,watched
SUNDAY,EVENING,[USA,UK],B2JO1owWbeLn,[WGdZ5qZmLw0,abcdef]
MONDAY,EVENING,[China],xxx,[abc,def,ijk]
```

According to the doc https://www.tensorflow.org/api_docs/python/tf/feature_column, "day_of_week" and "day_period" can be represented as "categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list". This is straightforward. However, "country", and "watched" are a list of categorical variables. I'd like to merge each categorical variable in a list to an embedding. From the same doc, a "tf.feature_column.embedding_column" would do the trick.

The following function builds columns representing the above input.

```
def build_model_columns():
    day_of_week = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list('day_of_week', day_of_weeks)
    day_period = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list('day_period', day_periods)
    country = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list('country', countries)
    watched = tf.feature_column.categorical_column_with_vocabulary_list('watched', movie_emb_ids)

    columns = [
        tf.feature_column.indicator_column(day_of_week),
        tf.feature_column.indicator_column(day_period),
        tf.feature_column.embedding_column(country, 8),
        tf.feature_column.embedding_column(watched, 32)
    ]
    return columns
```

The following is a function generating training dataset

```
def tensor_to_array(tensor):
    length = tf.size(tf.string_split([tensor], ""))
    sub = tf.substr(tensor, 1, length-2) # remove the leading '[' and trailing ']'
    splits = tf.string_split([sub], delimiter=',')
    return splits

def train_input_fn():
    train_files = "train.csv"
    target_files = "target.csv"
    target_table, target_ids = read_table_lookup(target_files, "movie")

    def preprocess(day_of_week, day_period, country, movie_id, watched):

        features = {
            'day_of_week': day_of_week,
            'day_period': day_period,
            'country': tensor_to_array(country),
            'watched': tensor_to_array(watched)

        }
        # target_table is a lookup table converting "movie_id" to integer "id"
        return features, target_table.lookup(movie_id) 

    dataset = (tf.contrib.data.CsvDataset(train_files, record_defaults, header=True)
           .map(preprocess, num_parallel_calls=5)
           .batch(batch_size=batch_size, drop_remainder=False)
           .repeat()
          )

    # iterator = dataset.make_initializable_iterator()
    # tf.add_to_collection(tf.GraphKeys.TABLE_INITIALIZERS, iterator.initializer)

    return dataset
```

The following is a code snippet to create and train an estimator.

```
hidden_units = [512, 512]
record_defaults = [[""]] * 5
columns = build_model_columns()
estimator = tf.estimator.DNNClassifier(model_dir="dir",
                                   feature_columns=columns,
                                   hidden_units=hidden_units,
                                   n_classes=len(target_ids)) # length of all targets

estimator.train(input_fn=train_input_fn)
```

I got no error and it seems like everything should work as expected but the training loss is so huge and fluctuating around 3,xxx and never decreasing. See below

```
INFO:tensorflow:Calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Done calling model_fn.
INFO:tensorflow:Create CheckpointSaverHook.
INFO:tensorflow:Graph was finalized.
INFO:tensorflow:Running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Done running local_init_op.
INFO:tensorflow:Saving checkpoints for 0 into /home/cocoza4/movie_models/deep/model.ckpt.
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 6538.0645, step = 0
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 17.353
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 3596.562, step = 100 (5.764 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 17.434
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 3504.936, step = 200 (5.736 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 17.4234
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 3500.0488, step = 300 (5.739 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 17.5321
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 3480.702, step = 400 (5.705 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 17.4534
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 3517.599, step = 500 (5.729 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 17.3421
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 3446.142, step = 600 (5.769 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 17.313
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 3281.3088, step = 700 (5.776 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 17.4421
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 3326.7336, step = 800 (5.731 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 17.3619
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 3464.902, step = 900 (5.762 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 17.2013
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 3364.2153, step = 1000 (5.813 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 17.4429
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 3410.449, step = 1100 (5.734 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 17.0483
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 3351.018, step = 1200 (5.866 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 17.4214
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 3386.995, step = 1300 (5.740 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 17.7965
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 3263.6074, step = 1400 (5.617 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 17.6944
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 3321.574, step = 1500 (5.652 sec)
INFO:tensorflow:global_step/sec: 17.3603
INFO:tensorflow:loss = 3234.7761, step = 1600 (5.760 sec)
```

I wonder if I've done something wrong when preparing the training data?

thanks

Peeranat F.

Answer (score 0):

The first thing that caught my attention is the number of hidden units. I would try to adjust your hidden units. Usually the layers should decrease in size, so I would try `[512,256,128]`